# Django 1.5.4 Python Count a Loop

Tags: python, django, django-1.5

I'm trying to get the amount of times these loops have gone into a variable. (I know they're static right now, but eventually they'll be based of data coming from other places).

I know how to do it in other languages, but can't for the life of me figure out how to do it in Python / Django.

In PHP I'd use a `i++` in the loop and just display the final value of `i`

Django 1.5.4
Python 2.7

```
View

def channel(request):
    values = []
    values2 = []
    for i in range(1,11):
    values.append(i)
    for i2 in range(1,6):
    values2.append(i2)

Template

{% for value in values %}
<insert random html here>
    {{ count_of_loop }}
    {% for value2 in values2  %}
    {{ count_of_loop2 }}
    <insert random html here>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use [Counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) in template.

```
{{ forloop.counter }}
```

A example:

```
{% for value in values %}
{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
   Do something.
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This actually worked perfectly for what I needed. I just had to rethink how I was approaching the HTML. Thank you. My "Do something." was `{{ forloop.revcounter }}` to show the max times that the counter had been ran on the first time of running it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in the template
`{{forloop.counter}}` The current iteration of the loop (1-indexed)

`{{forloop.counter0}}` The current iteration of the loop (0-indexed)

Or if you want to set range within template use  | for example:

```
def channel(request):
    range1 = 11
    range2 = 6


{% for i in 0|range1 %}  
   {{ forloop.counter }}
      {% for y in 0|range2 %}  
         {{ forloop.counter }}
      {% endfor %}  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But I'm not using i++ (or the equiv) in the loop. I'm importing a range and doing a for loop from the view. I guess what I'm looking for is how do I define `value.count`?

Comment: @AndrewWilson i posted an easier way to get what you want.